# Use many call apoc.do.when

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I want to create movie node and create a relation between movie and genre from a csv

CSV file:
id|title|release|action|adventure|animation|childrens|comedy|crime|documentary|drama|fantasy|film-Noir|horror|musical|mystery|romance|sci-Fi|thriller|war|western
1|Toy Story (1995)|01-Jan-1995|0|0|1|1|1|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0
2|GoldenEye (1995)|01-Jan-1995|1|1|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|1|0|0
3|Four Rooms (1995)|01-Jan-1995|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|1|0|0

My cypher query

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'https://www.dropbox.com/s/yho5i7kqocpkh9r/u.item.csv?dl=1' AS line FIELDTERMINATOR '|'
CREATE (n:Movie {id: toInteger(line.id),title: line.title, release: date(line.date)})
WITH line,n
CALL apoc.do.when(toInteger(line.action) = 1, 'MATCH(g:Genre) WHERE g.id = 1 MERGE ($n)-[IS]->(g)','', {n:n})
CALL apoc.do.when(toInteger(line.adventure) = 1, 'MATCH(g:Genre) WHERE g.id = 2 MERGE ($n)-[IS]->(g)','', {n:n})
....
```

For each genre (action, adventure,....) if the movie's genre is equal 1, I create a relation between genre node and movie node

Could you help me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest another approach:

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'https://www.dropbox.com/s/yho5i7kqocpkh9r/u.item.csv?dl=1' AS line FIELDTERMINATOR '|'

// get all the genre names belonging to a movie
WITH line,[key IN keys(line) WHERE key <> "id" AND line[key] = "1" | key] AS genres

// MERGE the movie using the id, SET the other properties
MERGE (movie:Movie {id: toInteger(line.id)})
ON CREATE SET movie.title = line.title, 
              movie.release = date(line.date)

// loop through the genre names and MERGE the :Genre nodes when needed
FOREACH (genre IN genres |
     MERGE (g:Genre {type:genre})
     MERGE (movie)-[:IS]->(g)
)
```

For the first two rows, it creates this:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your response, but genre node already exist

Genre{id:1, type:'action'}, etc...

Comment: in that case,you can use MERGE (g:Genre {type:genre})  instead of MERGE (g:Genre {name:genre})  (I changed it in my answer)